# Check if a Checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking if a checkbox is checked, and if so, setting the visibility of a DIV.

However, the property check is failing. Nothing happens. When I put an alert before the "if", the alert fires. But with the if's, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.cbFee').click(function () {
    if ($('.cbFee').prop('checked')) {
        $('.grpAnnualFee').hide();
    } else {
        $('.grpAnnualFee').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't click the first checkbox? You should test for `this.checked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$('.cbFee').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {   
        $('.grpAnnualFee').hide();
    } else {
        $('.grpAnnualFee').show();
    }
});
```

OR

```
$('.cbFee').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {   
         $('.grpAnnualFee').hide();
    } else {
         $('.grpAnnualFee').show();
    }
});
```

and while dealing with checkboxes it is better to use `.change()` instead of `.click()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('.cbFee').is(':checked')`